# Why does the Yii Form Checkbox Login Form Posts both hidden and checkbox inputs?

Tags: php, checkbox, yii

Using Yii 1.1.15

I am using the default login form:

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="row rememberMe">
<input id="ytUser_rememberMe" type="hidden" value="0" name="User[rememberMe]">
<input name="User[rememberMe]" id="User_rememberMe" value="1" type="checkbox">
<label for="User_rememberMe">Remember Me</label>
</div>
```

In the View:

```
<div class="row rememberMe">
    <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->label($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
</div>
```

What is posted (Form Data):

```
User[rememberMe]:0
User[rememberMe]:1
```

Even though the checkbox is checked, it is always 0.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore them.

If the checkbox isn't checked, Yii will take the first value (default value), which is 0.

If the checkbox is checked, the second value will override the first value when the controller does this:

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
```